# Where do I place the PHP file in Wordpress that I want to run on a form submission

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a form on a WordPress page as follows:

```
<form id="submissions-form" action="submissions-upload.php" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="submissions_upload">
    ...
</form>
```

Where should I place my `submissions-upload.php` file?

I specifically want to run the `submissions-upload.php` code, not code on my page.

I don't know where wordpress pages are meant to be stored. All I know is that it doesn't work on the root page.

Comment: If you'd like to use an external file for processing the request, simply upload to the directory where the file containing HTML form codes is. For example, if it is example.com/contact-us, upload to your site root directory. If it is example.com/path/contact-us, upload to the "path" folder. (I am assuming that you want the external PHP to be in the same folder looking at your action attribute).

Comment: Lets say I had my page on www.mywebsite.com/mypage/

When I place the code in the root, it doesn't work and when I place it in a folder on root called mypage it still doesn't work.

Comment: My path is example.com/submissions/, but storing it on the root isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same page ... Like as

```
<?php 
   if($_POST){
       print_r($_POST);
     }
 ?> 
 <form id="submissions-form" action="#" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="submissions_upload">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Nevermind, this doesn't seem to work nicely with all my code when switching between Visual and Text views, I want it on a different file to solve that.